Allure Reports "Cannot find module 'allure-cypress/commands' " for Cypress BDD Framwork using Cucumber
I am working on Cypress BBD Framework using cucumber:
The following are dependencies installed:
 "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^13.11.0",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": false,
    "stepDefinitions": "cypress/e2e/Cucumber/tests/"
  }

My Current Folder Structure:
.
└── CypressCucumberFramework-Version1/
    ├── cypress/
    │   ├── e2e/
    │   │   └── Cucumber/
    │   │       ├── features/
    │   │       │   ├── flightReservation.feature
    │   │       │   ├── registerPage.feature
    │   │       │   └── signOn.feature
    │   │       ├── pages/
    │   │       │   ├── flightReservation.js
    │   │       │   ├── registerPage.js
    │   │       │   └── signOn.js
    │   │       └── tests/
    │   │           ├── testFlightReservation.cy.js
    │   │           ├── testRegisterPage.cy.js
    │   │           └── testSignOnPage.cy.js
    │   ├── fixtures/
    │   │   └── testData.json
    │   ├── support/
    │   │   ├── commands.js
    │   │   └── e2e.js
    │   ├── screenshots
    │   └── videos
    ├── node_modules
    ├── cypress.config.js
    ├── package-lock.json
    └── package.json

I am able to successfully execute the tests from Cypress Test Runner and VScode Terminal when Allure Cypress Reporting dependencies are not installed.

So, when I add the Allure Cypress Reporting dependencies below"
package.json
 "devDependencies": {
    "allure-commandline": "^2.29.0",
    "allure-cypress": "^3.0.0-beta.3",
    "cypress": "^13.11.0",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": false,
    "stepDefinitions": "cypress/e2e/Cucumber/tests/"
  }

cypress.config.js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default
const { allureCypress } = require("allure-cypress/reporter");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  video:true,
  screenshotOnRunFailure: true,
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
      //Cucumber PreProcessor
      on('file:preprocessor', cucumber())
      //Allure Reports
      allureCypress(on);
    },
    specPattern: "cypress/e2e/Cucumber/features/*.feature"
  },
  env:{
    registerPageURL:'https://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/register.php',
    signOnPageURL:'https://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/login.php',
    flightReservation: 'https://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/reservation.php',
  } 
});

e2e.js
// Import commands.js using ES2015 syntax:
import './commands';
import "allure-cypress/commands";

So, while executing the tests with above mentioned configurations and dependencies for Allure Cypress Reporting i am facing the below issues:
Referance: https://allurereport.org/docs/cypress/
Error:
The error was:

Error: Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module 'allure-cypress/commands' from 'C:\Users\angshumanbasak\CypressCucumberFramework-Version1\cypress\support\e2e.js'
    required by C:\Users\angshumanbasak\CypressCucumberFramework-Version1\cypress\support\e2e.js
    at C:\Users\angshumanbasak\CypressCucumberFramework-Version1\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:146:35
    at processDirs (C:\Users\angshumanbasak\CypressCucumberFramework-Version1\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:299:39)
    at isdir (C:\Users\angshumanbasak\CypressCucumberFramework-Version1\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:306:32)
    at C:\Users\angshumanbasak\CypressCucumberFramework-Version1\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:34:69
    at callback (C:\Users\angshumanbasak\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\13.11.0\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\@packages\server\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:299:20)
    at callback (C:\Users\angshumanbasak\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\13.11.0\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\@packages\server\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:299:20)
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:197:21)


This occurred while Cypress was compiling and bundling your test code. This is usually caused by:

- A missing file or dependency
- A syntax error in the file or one of its dependencies

Fix the error in your code and re-run your tests.


While I have the import "allure-cypress/commands"; in e2e.js I am not able to comprehend why I am facing this module dependency error.
Any help to resolve the issue will really be appreciated !

In the beta.3 version, there is no allure-cypress/commands folder, look under the node-modules/allure-cypress folder - there is only /dist folder.
So remove the line import "allure-cypress/commands". If you have gotten this from some old notes and wish to follow them, downgrade to v.2.15.1.

Okay, so downgrading to v.2.15.1 and removing the import "allure-cypress/commands" worked. But, not allure-results is not generating the desired files, its an empty folder. @Eva Sorhaug
